How does the Ingress affinity work if I have 3 pods and 1 service?
If I have three pods, and one service, and I create the ingress like this below:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sticky-session-test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"

spec:
  rules:
  - host: stickyingress.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /

I feel like this ingress just route the http to the service, not the pod. How does it work internal?
I have verify the ingress above, and it actually work.

Please add your complete setup (i.e. the Service definition, and the most important parts of the Deployment definition, at least the names etc.). And it is a little unclear what you are actually asking...

Under normal circumstances, the request flows from ingress to service. I want to ask why configuring the following can achieve pod-level sticky session:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800" @AnoE

Per your comment, you are asking how it works that the affinity "sticks" to a specific pod, seeing that in the configuration the connection is between Ingress and Service, not Ingress and Pod (or  Deployment).
According to e.g. this random search result, the value of the cookie simply is the pod name (i.e., the fully specified "final" name). So once a user's browser has this cookie, the ingress will filter the possible candidate pods (which it finds via Service or whatever rules you have in the config), and if the pod mentioned in the cookies is still in the list, it will be used.

According to the doc, I think the cookie can be any value, not only the pod's name.
